# get dict every item and get a new list in one line

Tags: python

I have a dict,like this:

```
{'brand': ['Three Squirrels', 'liang', 'BE'],
  'op': ['交', '差'],
  'cate': ['aaaa','bbbb','cccc']
}
```

Now, I want to make a new list,like this:

```
 [
 {'brand':'Three Squirrels','op':'交','cate':'aaaa'},
 {'brand':'Three Squirrels','op':'差','cate':'bbbb'},
 {'brand':'liang','op':'交','cate':'aaaa'},
 {'brand':'liang','op':'交','cate':'bbbb'},
 .....
 .....
]
```

list len is 3*2*3 = 18

How can I do this in one line code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all possible values via [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
Then you can iterate through the values and create your list of dictionaries by zipping together keys and values

```
from itertools import product

dct = {'brand': ['Three Squirrels', 'liang', 'BE'],
  'op': ['交', '差'],
  'cate': ['aaaa','bbbb','cccc']
}

#Get the list of keys
keys = dct.keys()

#Iterate through the values, and zip key and value together
result = [ dict(zip(keys, item)) for item in product(*dct.values())]

print(result)
print(len(result))
```

The output will be

```
[{'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'aaaa'}, 
{'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'cccc'}, 
{'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'aaaa'},
 {'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'Three Squirrels', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'cccc'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'aaaa'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'cccc'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'aaaa'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'liang', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'cccc'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'aaaa'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '交', 'cate': 'cccc'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'aaaa'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'bbbb'}, 
{'brand': 'BE', 'op': '差', 'cate': 'cccc'}]

18
```